# Are tables the same for PHP

Tags: php, html-table

I am not understanding I have this right now is the tables for html will work with PHP or are they different. I understand how to do tables in HTML with the CSS but I am not to sure with PHP. I am new to PHP and this might be a stupid question to most of you. I am just hoping someone can explain so I have a better understanding of it.

I am still not understanding how to display something in a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser only reads `html`.

`PHP` is a programing language, interpreted by the server, used to generate `html` that the browser reads.

That said there are no such thing as `PHP` tables. Just do a table the normal way. Take a look at the example bellow that uses PHP to create a "dynamic" table. Now imagine that the `$animals` gets pulled from a database...

Example:
`my-table-generator.php`

```
<?php
$animals = array("dog", "cat", "duck");
?>

<table>
   <tr>
   <?php
       foreach($animals as $animal) 
       {
          echo "<td>".$animal."</td>";
       }
   ?>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ok now I am working with money for the month in PHP and it said to create a table using PHP. But if I use it the regular way I know i don't need to using anything that has if or else in their. Now with the array i do know about but with this problem i almost needed it to look like a bank statement if that makes any sense. If not I can explain a little bit more on it.

Comment: @andy sorry, didn't get what you need. Try to describe it in terms of logic steps.

Comment: I am to display so money things in a table using PHP. I understand how to create a table in HTML but not in PHP. But Know i understand that the tables are the same no matter what you are doing. I am looking at the example you put up there and it somewhat makes sense. I am using starting balance purchase,ATM deposit,eared, and purchase again. And after each one i am suppose to have the new balance. I do have that worked out. The only thing is doing this table for the PHP.

Comment: Ok I guess what I am also asking This is what i have echo "<p> Starting balance:" .sprintf("$%.2f",$balance)."</p>"; so I would do the for each($balance as $balance { then insert the echo "<p> <td>Starting balance:</td>" .sprintf("$%.2f",$balance)."</p>";} and so on and so on right?

Comment: @andy It will be helpdful if you can create a sample table in plain HTML of what you want. Then look at how you are getting the values to put in that table. Only then can you use PHP to help you generate the table. Sounds like you need a loop that goes through a set of transactions, do some calculations and output a row in a table. Where is the data coming from? What are the calculations? How would you know that you have gotten to the last transaction?

Answer (score 1):

PHP helps you send dynamic HTML to the browser. The HTML always remain the same regardless of the backend language you are using. So just use regular HTML and use PHP to render it. For instance if you want to display multiple rows of some data coming from the DB, you will utilize a PHP loop to print out the `<tr><td></td></tr>`

example:

```
for($i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++){
   echo "<tr><td>$i</td></tr>";
}
```

Probably not a very good example but hopefully it will get the message across.